# Parse json array from webserver

Tags: java, android, json

I'm going to parse a json array from web server to android app.The array looks like this

```
{"Level":
         [
         {"route":[{"lat":38.889762,"lgn":-77.081764},
         {"lat":38.89096,"lgn":-77.081916}]}, 
         {"route":[{"lat":38.889762,"lgn":-77.081764},
         {"lat":38.89096,"lgn":-77.081916}]},
         {"route":[{"lat":38.889762,"lgn":-77.081764},
         {"lat":38.89096,"lgn":-77.081916}]}
         ]
}
```

my java code is

```
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
    JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("Level");
    rlevel = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    System.out.println("*****JARRAY*****"+jArray.length());

    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){


     JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

     jlat = json_data.getDouble("lat");
     jlgn = json_data.getDouble("lgn");}
```

but not works! any idea?after this i want to save each route into an array (etc $plan[1]=first route from json, $plan[2]=second route from json)

Comment: After you get "level" you need to get "route" too the same way you did with "level"

Comment: could you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

//code is a String where you saved the json

```
JSonObject json= new JsonParser().parse(code).getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray jArray= json.getAsJsonArray("Level");
rLevel=new ArrayList<LatLng>();

//notice the use of the size() method. There is not length() method defined for ArrayList
System.out.println("*****JARRAY*****"+jArray.size());

for(int i=0;i<jArray.size();i++){

//notice that inside the Level Array you have route-arrays
    JSonObject level_item = jArray.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
    JSonArray route= level_item.getAsJSonArray("route");

//now I don't know exactly what data you want to extract, since there are 2
//pairs of LatLng, for the first one:
jlat = route.get(0).get("lat").getAsDouble();
jlgn= route.get(0).get("lgn").getASDouble();
```

The exact names for methods and JsonObjects tend to differ from a library to another, but the principle is the same.

Comment: i have this error [2013-07-29 04:02:13 - ddmlib] Broken pipe
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
 at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:94)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)